# ReferenceError: _webpack_require_ is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, here-api

I am trying to do this guide [Here React JS API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.7/dev_guide/topics/react-practices.html),
but I always just get a white screen with the here watermark and without a map and this error to.

```
ReferenceError: _webpack_require_ is not defined 2 6c60a8cc-4769-4b0e-932b-dbe27b7df713:1676:33
<anonym> blob:http://localhost:3000/6c60a8cc-4769-4b0e-932b-dbe27b7df713:1676
<anonym> blob:http://localhost:3000/6c60a8cc-4769-4b0e-932b-dbe27b7df713:18966
<anonym> blob:http://localhost:3000/6c60a8cc-4769-4b0e-932b-dbe27b7df713:18967
```

Does someone know what to do?

Env:

WSL 2 : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Node v16.13.0

Npm 8.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to resolve this issue is, add the [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) dependency to your project, and then add to your root folder a `config-overrides.js` file with the following contents:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.node = { global: false }
    return config
}
```

Finally, change the start script in `package.json` to use react-app-rewired, the scripts object should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```